# Which function in DolphinDB is similar to the lag operation?

Tags: dolphindb

For example, the original data looks like this:

| ID | x |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 11 |
| 3 | 12 |
| 4 | 13 |
| 5 | 14 |
| 6 | 15 |
| 7 | 16 |
| 8 | 17 |
| 9 | 18 |
| 10 | 19 |

After doing lag operation on the ID column, the following results are obtained:

| ID | x | lag_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |  |
| 2 | 11 | 1 |
| 3 | 12 | 2 |
| 4 | 13 | 3 |
| 5 | 14 | 4 |
| 6 | 15 | 5 |
| 7 | 16 | 6 |
| 8 | 17 | 7 |
| 9 | 18 | 8 |
| 10 | 19 | 9 |

Answer (score 0):

the [prev](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/p/prev.html), [next](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/n/next.html), and [move](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/m/move.html) functions in DolphinDB can meet the above requirements. Take "prev" as an example:

```py
n = 10
ID = take(1..10, n)
x = take(10..20, n)
t = table(ID, x)

select ID, x, prev(ID) as prev_ID from t
```

result:

[image]